# Case com parâmetro no Interbase 2017

Tags: sql

Boa noite pessoal, sempre usei Firebird, porém decidi experimentar o interbase 2017 para aplicativos mobile. O seguinte SQL funciona normalmente no Firebird e no SQLite. Mas estou quebrando a cabeça para tentar fazer funcionar no Interbase 2017. Se eu removo os parâmetros do Case o código funciona.

```
SELECT P.ID_PESSOA,
       P.RAZAO_SOCIAL,
       P.NOME_FANTASIA,
       P.ID_CATEGORIA,
       P.TIPO_PESSOA,
       P.NUMERO,
       P.ID_ENDERECO,
       P.BAIRRO,
       E.ENDERECO,
       E.ENDERECO || ', ' || P.NUMERO || ' ' || P.BAIRRO AS ENDERECO_COMPLETO
  FROM PESSOA P
  JOIN ENDERECO E ON (P.ID_ENDERECO = E.ID_ENDERECO)
 WHERE P.ID_CATEGORIA = CASE :ID_CATEGORIA WHEN 0 THEN P.ID_CATEGORIA
                                                  ELSE :ID_CATEGORIA
                                           END
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pelo visto parece que a sua ideia é aplicar o `WHERE` apenas quando o `:ID_CATEGORIA` for diferente de zero. E quando o `:ID_CATEGORIA` for zero, você quer que todos os resultados sejam trazidos.

Tente usar um `OR`:

```
WHERE :ID_CATEGORIA = 0 OR P.ID_CATEGORIA = :ID_CATEGORIA
```

Comment: Bom dia amigo, funcionou perfeitamente! Muito obrigado por sua ajuda!!!